# How to set and change a Grease Pencil object's material in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, grease-pencil

I have a question about the material of a grease pencil.
How do I set different materials for the Grease Pencil objects duplicated in AnimationNodes?

Like motion graphics, I want to duplicate a grease pencil object to stagger its color and timing.
I was able to use the Build Modifier and Animation Nodes to stagger the replication and timing, but not the colors.
For example, object 1 to be red, object 2 to be blue, and so on, but they all have the same color.
Apparently only the last one of the Loops has been generated.
However, when I check with Loop VIewer, multiple materials should have their own colors.

I'd appreciate if you could answer this question.
I have attached a .blend file, so I hope you can check it.

[image]

Comment: Hello, which version of AN are you using ?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm using AN version 2.2.1 for macOS.

Answer (score 1):

The Material Instancer node didn't work on my AN-version, so I used a Create Material List node and fed that in the Invoke Subprogram node. Now that I had a working tree I played around a little bit. After checking the Deep Copy option of the Object Instancer the different colours for the individual strokes appeared.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried it as your answer and it was reflected normally.
Different colours for the individual strokes appeared.
It was very helpful.